# Agregar columnas, pivoteando un DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Tengo la siguiente base en `pd.DataFrame`:

```
Index ID  Date     Days     Name
1     1   5-1-20   10       Josh
2     1   9-1-20   10       Josh
3     1   19-1-20  6        Josh
4     2   1-1-20   10       Mike
5     3   1-4-20   10       George
6     4   1-2-20   10       Rose
7     4   11-5-20  5        Rose
8     5   1-9-20   10       Mark
9     6   1-4-21   10       Joe
10    7   1-1-21   10       Jill
```

Y deseo que los ID no se me repitan en la base de datos, expandiendo las columnas Date y Days según lo que sea necesario. En este caso, 3 columnas de Dates y 3 columnas de days, ya que el ID 1  es el que mas se repite.
El resultado deseado seria el siguiente:

```
Index ID  Date 1   Date 2  Date 3   Days1  Days2   Days3  Name
1     1   5-1-20   9-1-20  19-1-20  10     10      6      Josh
2     2   1-1-20                    10                    Mike
3     3   1-4-20                    10                    George
4     4   1-2-20   11-5-20          10     5              Rose
5     5   1-9-20                    10                    Mark
6     6   1-4-21                    10                    Joe
7     7   1-1-21                    10                    Jill
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lo primero que debes hacer es agrupar tu dataframe por los identificadores que quieras, en este caso ID y Name, utilizando `list` como función para agregar las columnas que quieres expandir

```
df = df.groupby(['ID', 'Name']).agg({'Date': list, 'Days': list}).reset_index()
```

Esto te genera un dataframe de este tipo:

| ID | Name | Date | Days |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Josh | ['5-1-20', '9-1-20', '19-1-20'] | [10, 10, 6] |
| 2 | Mike | ['1-1-20'] | [10] |
| 3 | George | ['1-4-20'] | [10] |
| 4 | Rose | ['1-2-20', '11-5-20'] | [10, 5] |
| 5 | Mark | ['1-9-20'] | [10] |
| 6 | Joe | ['1-4-21'] | [10] |
| 7 | Jill | ['1-1-21'] | [10] |

Ahora, para expandir esas listas a columnas podemos hacer una pequeña función que calcule el número de columnas resultantes y genere un dataframe con la serie de esa columna. Para esto podemos utilizar el método toList() y luego añadir esas columnas a nuestro dataframe existente.

```
def expand(column, d):
    expanded = pd.DataFrame(d[column].tolist(), index=d.index)  # creamos un df tomando como base la serie
    expanded.columns = [f'{column} {int(x)+1}' for x in expanded.columns]  # renombramos las columnas
    return pd.concat([d, expanded], axis=1).drop(columns=[column])  # Unimos los dos dfs y eliminamos la columna
```

Ahora sólo deberíamos llamar a nuestra función para cada columna que queramos expandir:

```
df = expand('Date', df)
df = expand('Days', df)
```

---

Todo el script sería simplemente:

```
def expand(column, d):
    expanded = pd.DataFrame(d[column].tolist(), index=d.index)
    expanded.columns = [f'{column} {int(x)+1}' for x in expanded.columns]
    return pd.concat([d, expanded], axis=1).drop(columns=[column])


df = df.groupby(['ID', 'Name']).agg({'Date': list, 'Days': list}).reset_index()
df = expand('Date', df)
df = expand('Days', df)
```

El resultado sería el siguiente (quitando los nan):

| ID | Name | Date 1 | Date 2 | Date 3 | Days 1 | Days 2 | Days 3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Josh | 5-1-20 | 9-1-20 | 19-1-20 | 10 | 10 | 6 |
| 2 | Mike | 1-1-20 |  |  | 10 |  |  |
| 3 | George | 1-4-20 |  |  | 10 |  |  |
| 4 | Rose | 1-2-20 | 11-5-20 |  | 10 | 5 |  |
| 5 | Mark | 1-9-20 |  |  | 10 |  |  |
| 6 | Joe | 1-4-21 |  |  | 10 |  |  |
| 7 | Jill | 1-1-21 |  |  | 10 |  |  |